# WooCommerce - get count of variation attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get/count the amount of variation attributes for at WooCommerce product. If I var_dump the product I see the amount here: https://take.ms/1kJXg but I can't get the value as a variable so I can use it for an if condition.

I have tried a lot of combinations from other questions but without success.

I have come up with this, but missing the code to get the actual code for the var $variationattributes?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'if_multiple_attributes' );
function if_multiple_attributes() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {

        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        var_dump($variations);

        // I wish to be able to do something like this

        $varitionattributes = ?????;

        if ($varitionattributes > 1){
            // do something
        }
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `foreach` if you multiple entries and if not then using associate array method or using object based array method you can retrieve the data.

**Eg for Associate array value fetch, with your variable:**

```
count($variations['attributes']) --- This will result the count as you want
```

**Eg for Object array value fetch, with your variable:**

```
count($variations->attributes) --- This will result the count as you want
```

Please try the process once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up with this:


`$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
        if ($variation === reset($variations)){
            $variableattributes = count($variation['attributes']);
        }
    }
    if ($variableattributes < 2) {
// do stuff
}
`

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Appreciated and I am happy that one of the above code worked for you.